# In Google Analytics Android app, Is there something called non session events?

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Say, there is a background service in app, which fires event on analytics.
Now i don't want that event to create a session on Google analytics.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using .setNonIntraction(true) in your analytics tracking.

```
Tracker t = getGoogleTracker();
t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder().setCategory(category)
.setAction(event)
.setLabel(label).setNonInteraction(true)
.setValue(l)
.build());
```

This works for me like a charm !!!